# Is it possible to re-format a text string to merge common sub-strings and sum their associated numeric values?

Tags: python

I am a Python beginner. I need to re-format text similar to the following string.

Blue: 4; Red: 1; Red: 2; Green: 3; Yellow: 10; Yellow: 15;

Is there a way to use Python to combine the matching sub-strings of colors and, when they match, sum the associated numeric values after the colon?

Blue: 4; Red: 3; Green: 3; Yellow: 25;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes, there certainly is. But you seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Like @YevhenKuzmovych said, try to write it yourself, then if it doesn't work ask a question about your issue on stackoverflow. But don't ask how to do something you haven't even tried. This is an easy problem I'm sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There will be many ways to do this in Python - the problem is a bit more complex than you are likely to think as a beginner.  What you need to do generally with a bigger problem is to divide it into smaller tasks that are likely to be short and easy to implement:

- You've got a nicely formatted but variable-element string there, with clear semicolon separators.  You'll want to split this string into all the substrings.  Check the python docs for something to split strings.
- Each element in the split string is again a well-formatted piece of information: colour : value.  You'll want to split this again, or maybe use another method to extract the two parts from this fixed-element string, such as a regex.
- Now that you are able to get a colour and value from each element, you'll want to track this.  You'll want to associate every colour with the sum of numeric values.  This suggests you might want key/value pairs, an associative array, which in Python is represented by dictionary.
- You should have all the elements to piece together your solution now: a dictionary to track your work, splitting the string, extracting the data, updating the dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this is not most effective way but firstly you can split your string with ";" after that operation you got each color-value pair. Then, you can split each color-value pair string with ":" to obtain color and pair seperately. So you have a list name color_value_pair and each index of this list contains also list; first index contains color and second index contains value.

```
my_dict={}
color_value_pair=[item.split(":") for item in my_string.split(";") if item!='']
```

After obtaining all key-value pairs you can check the color is new or already exists in loop.

```
for item in color_value_pair:
    color=item[0].strip()
    value=int(item[1].strip())
    if color in my_dict:
        my_dict[color]+=value
    else:
        my_dict[color]=value
```

And if you want to convert to string again;

```
string="".join(f"{color}:{value};" for color,value in my_dict.items())
```

Full code;

```
my_string="Blue: 4; Red: 1; Red: 2; Green: 3; Yellow: 10; Yellow: 15;"
my_dict={}
color_value_pair=[item.split(":") for item in my_string.split(";") if item!='']
for item in color_value_pair:
    color=item[0].strip()
    value=int(item[1].strip())
    if color in my_dict:
        my_dict[color]+=value
    else:
        my_dict[color]=value
string="".join(f"{color}:{value};" for color,value in my_dict.items())
print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
#Blue: 4; Red: 1; Red: 2; Green: 3; Yellow: 10; Yellow: 15;

colors =["Blue 4","Red 1","Red 2","Green 3","Yellow 10","Yellow 15"]
newColors = []

while True:
  if not colors:
      break;

  tempColor = colors[0]
  del colors[0]
  res =int(tempColor[-2:])
  tempCount = 0
  while True:
      if tempCount == len(colors):
          break;
      if tempColor[0:-2] == colors[tempCount][0:-2]:
          res = res+int(colors[tempCount][-2:])
          del colors[tempCount]
          tempCount = 0
      else:
          tempCount = tempCount+1
                
  newColors.append(str(tempColor[0:-2]+" "+str(res)))
  print(newColors)
```

This is the output I got:

```
['Blue 4', 'Red 3', 'Green 3', 'Yellow  25']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from itertools import groupby
s = "Blue: 4; Red: 1; Red: 2; Green: 3; Yellow: 10; Yellow: 15"
"; ".join((f"{k}: {sum(int(e.split(': ')[1]) for e in g)}" 
          for k, g 
          in groupby(sorted(s.split("; ")), lambda x: x.split(":")[0])))
```

Output: `'Blue: 4; Green: 3; Red: 3; Yellow: 25'`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Apart from the lack of explanation, your solution is very hard to comprehend even for the experienced python developer. There's no need to write everything in one statement, the variables are just single letters, etc. And this is not even a valid python code to be precise.